# Can I only call Realm.getInstance() once in Application?

Tags: android, realm

I am toying with Realm and I always find that Realm.getInstance() is called during Activity create and instance closed in Activity destroy. May I know is there any side impact that keep only one instance create and open all the time until the application is closed?

Comment: I saw in the specification that it keeps a counter for getInstance(). Therefore, you have to call X times close() if you call X times getInstance(). So, my question is like whether I can call once getInstance() in Application create and once close() in Application destroy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no Application onDestroy. Realm does the necessary caching internally, so it should be safe to call Realm.getInstance()/close() as many times as you want.

Trying to do your own caching will not make anything more efficient. You can read about how to control the Realm instance life cycles here:

https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#controlling-the-lifecycle-of-realm-instances
https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#closing-realm-instances

Comment: Thanks for your information and sorry for my mistake. By the way, may I ask one more follow up question? As you mention "many times as you want", is there any drawback for me to call getInstance()/close() in every db operation instead of doing in Activity onCreate()/onDestroy()? (As I wanna make the things decoupling from Activity)

Comment: There is a small overhead if you fully close a Realm file (as we need to validate it when opening it again), and your RealmObjects are only available while the Realm is open. So for background threads closing on each operation is fine. On the UI thread, you most likely only want to do it in onCreate/onDestroy

Comment: Thanks for providing details. ;)