# Secondary .realm file getInstance taking too long

Tags: android, kotlin, realm, realm-mobile-platform, realm-migration

> By secondary `.realm` file I mean a realm file which is not the `default.realm` file.

I have two `.realm` files - one being the standard `default.realm` and the other being say `aux.realm`.

Things work as they should under normal circumstances, but when I perform a heavy operation (multiple tables undergo `.deleteAllFromRealm()` and re-sync everything) while this happens on a worker thread, the user is still free to perform any UI activities, whenever any interaction is performed involving the `aux.realm` instance, the app shuts with an ANR.

With some extensive debugging I found that the `getAuxRealmInstance` takes a lot of time to pass the instance, even though the value for it should be cached. This is in spite of the fact that its configuration already loaded lazily. Hence, it is unclear as to why it takes so much time?

I also though it might be an issue of transactions as there can be only one active transaction at a time, but what i'm not sure is that is the rule valid also through files, like can two realm files have their own `transactions` running in parallel?

My `aux.realm` file:

```
private const val FILE_NAME = "auxiliary.realm"
private val auxiliaryConfiguration  = lazy {
    RealmConfiguration.Builder()
            .name(FILE_NAME)
            .schemaVersion(AuxiliarySchemaVersionMappings.CURRENT_SCHEMA_VERSION)
            .modules(AuxiliaryRealmModule())
            .initialData {
                Log.d("AuxRealm", "running initial data migration: ")
                // initial version..
                // migrate the AppMetaData table from base realm to aux realm
                }
            }
            .migration(AuxiliaryRealmMigration())
            .build().also { Log.d("AuxRealm", "configuration created: ") }
}

fun getAuxiliaryRealmInstance(): Realm{
    return Realm.getInstance(auxiliaryConfiguration.value)
}

fun getAuxiliaryRealmInstanceAsync(callback: Realm.Callback): RealmAsyncTask{
    return Realm.getInstanceAsync(auxiliaryConfiguration.value, callback)
}
```

PS: The ANR goes away if I load the aux realm instance in async, which as mentioned above, points to the same problem.

Env variables: Realm: 5.4.2, Kotlin 1.2.51

Comment: I assume your `initialData` is a long-running transaction which happens on UI thread, therefore it can take a while. You could theoretically do some trickery with `Realm.getInstanceAsync()`.

Comment: The initialData doesnt have much, i tried with that, i even tried removing it, still it takes the same time, also the configuration static object is already initialized at application level. And as per the doc, the `initialData` would run only once right, still the anr appears everytime

Comment: @EpicPandaForce even though the Async thing works, what i'm unable to understand is that why does it take time to open an instance, even if it's in a separate file?

Comment: Maybe it's the migration? The migration is also a write transaction. But I recommend using the Method Profiling in AS profiler to see what method executed for long time

Comment: I did try the AS profiler, it took some 2-3 seconds to return the instance for the `aux.realm` file. I thought it might be a migration issue, so i cleared my app data and tried the same, this I suppose would recreate the schema from scratch and the realm file does not exists (not sure about this though, assuming this by the file.exists check in souce)

Comment: If you actually show where it takes a long time in Realm's methods then I'll know more. I recommend taking a screenshot

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178032/discussion-between-madscientist-and-epicpandaforce).

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by caching the realm instance:

```
private Realm auxiliaryRealmInstance;

fun getAuxiliaryRealmInstance(): Realm{
return auxiliaryRealmInstance == null ? Realm.getInstance(auxiliaryConfiguration.value) : auxiliaryRealmInstance;
}
```

This workaround should not be necessary because [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37693214/6071640) it's written that caching will not make anything more efficient. But I did not notice any disadvantages so far.